# Rspec request Active Model Serializer response doesn't contain root key

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, active-model-serializers, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to test a JSON endpoint (Rails 5) that is built using active model serializers gem (version 0.10.2) with the JSON adapter.

When I make the request from http://localhost:3000/api/posts I get the root node in the response so that it looks like the documentation:

```
{
  "posts": [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Awesome Post Tile",
    "content": "Post content"
  }]
}
```

but when I make the request in Rspec (version 3.5) like this:

> get '/api/posts'

the root node doesn't come through, so the response body looks like this:

```
[{
   "id": 1,
   "title": "Awesome Post Tile",
   "content": "Post content"
}]
```

My adapter is being set in an initializer:

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I don't really know enough about either as to whether this is an issue with AMS or Rspec or a setup problem on my part.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have enabled `include_root_in_json` for the development environment but not the test environment?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Comment: I checked the project source code and couldn't find any instances where I have used include_root_in_json.